# Angular ngfor loop displaying menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying create a menu and sub menu.. The structure  I want for my menu is mentioned below. Here is the demo I am trying I  am getting wrong structure.

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odvcsm.

```
"Sub Test": { // Main menu

 "Example1":"hai",//sub menu

 "Ex2":"hello"// sub menu

},
```

Comment: So you want three levels? Test -> Sub test -> Examples?

Comment: No only two level SubTest as main menu and  Example and Ex2 as sub menu

Comment: Then why do you have Test and Test3 at the top level in your example? If you want SubTest to be top level.

Comment: I am getting a json reponse on that format and want to extract SubTest as main menu and Example and Ex2 as sub menu

Comment: I'll need to see more code then including where you're getting the JSON response. You're saying the JSON response comes with Test as a top level value and sub test as the second level value?

Comment: Yes , You are right

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phsrpv

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. Yes it worked.. Many Thanks @Vega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more level of iteration here to go down in the sub-menu and to remove the top level label as it's no use for your case:

HTML

```
<ul *ngFor="let partner of list_value | keyvalue let i=index">

    <li *ngFor="let innerData of partner.value | keyvalue">


        <ul class="submenu">
            <li *ngFor="let innerData1 of innerData.value | keyvalue">
                {{innerData1.key}}
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of innerData1.value | keyvalue">
            {{item.value}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phsrpv)